# Best way to pass huge object from children to parent?

Tags: reactjs

I have a huge form and sumbit is triggered from outside the form

```
<App>
   <Form/>
   <Button/>   
</App>
```

The problem is that I need to have current form fields object in button component. I've tried to pass state through multiple layers by passing setState function:

```
const [formFields, setFormFields] = useState(null);    
<App>
   <Form setData={setFormFields}/>
   <Button data={formFields}/>   
</App>
```

And also to use redux dispatch(on form field changes) and useSelector in button component to get current data. But both methods seems to really slow down the application when I'm writing some text in input fields.

What would be the best solution to optimize it?

Comment: Why does your button component need the *whole* `formFields` state?

Comment: I need to have all form data for POST request which Is triggered from button component

Comment: I see. What about just passing a `submit` callback (and minor other things) to `Button`, so that the component containing `formfields` state does the post request?

Answer (score 0):

> really slow down the application when I'm writing some text in input fields.

This is because you're tying the form's **data** to the rendering. It would be fine to store the whole form through Redux as well (or wherever else you want), as long as you're not creating a dependency between the component's rendering lifecycle and those mutations in the form field's values.

Does the whole form need to update on each individual components' events? Not really. However, since the whole form is gathered in one big object, and that object's reference is changed after an update, then the whole component tree gets re-rendered.

To reduce the need for re-rendering, you can synchronize the data (note: the **data**, not the validations, etc...) outside of React, and only fetch it when you submit.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const externalFormData = {};

function Form() {
  return (
    <input
      onChange={function(ev) {
        externalFormData.input = ev.target.value;
      }}
    />
  );
}

export default function App() {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState();
  return (
    <div>
      <Form />
      <input
        type={"button"}
        onClick={function() {
          setFormData(externalFormData);
        }}
        value="Submit form"
      />
      <p>{`Submitted form is: ${JSON.stringify(formData)}`}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

If that's your choice, I suggest looking for some existing form library which handles that for you (including validation and etc).

Another idea would be decoupling this "big object" you mentioned into individual objects which gets updated separately, thus only triggering re-renders on the components affected by the value.

Comment: I will try your suggestion. I understand that the issue is about rerendering.. What If I would use onBlur instead of onChange? Could that cause any additional problems?

Comment: I can think of two things: 1. You won't be able to clear error fields as soon as the user starts typing with `onBlur` alone. 2. Before the user clicks the submit button, he won't know if there's an error in the current field, because `onBlur` will only trigger when he clicks the button. As far as getting the values, I think there won't be a problem.